# Where are shortcodes content usually located?

Tags: php, function, wordpress, shortcode

I going to update a content but I cannot find where's the post/content is located. So I deep dived in the code and then I found this shortcode `do_shortcode($value->post_content );`. Where can i find the content based on the shortcode given?

**EDIT:**

I found the shortcode in "page-home-1.php" file.

I want to edit the content of "What we do" tab  in this site: http://petlet.net.au/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme files search for add_shortcode("shortcode-name"). You will find a place where the short code exactly created and you can edit modify short code function and content.

Comment: Where's theme file search located? Im sorry Im not that familiar w/ wordpress

Comment: okay let me tell you from the beginning. First of all make sure that the content you want to change is in the code files other wise first check in wordpress pages. If your content really is in your code files.
Then go to theme directory where all theme files are placed like "header.php , footer.php" etc then search do_shortcode term as i have mentioned in my answer thorught out the files. But start searching from template files.
When you'll find your short code you can edit function or content anything which is in your shortcode

Comment: Okay sir i'll try it

Comment: Good Luck :)  happy coding